# Is there a convexhull / concavehull function in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, polygon

I want to create a function for generating polygons for model training. I plan to use this as a regularizer, possibly using the polygon area as a penalty, along with the number of coordinates, etc. I find libraries like alphashape for generating polygons to be complicated and prone to errors too often. Are there any other options?

I've tried to create polygons using the alphashape library but have encountered errors frequently. it's parameter sensitve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.